# Fetched JSON: object or array? iterating

Tags: angular

I cannot understand why I can't iterate through my JSON. In service file I fetch the JSON:

```
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
}
```

then I use it in my component:

```
posts$: Object;

constructor(private data: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getPosts().subscribe(
      data => { 
       this.posts$ = data;
    })
}
```

and I can iterate through it in my html template:

```
<li *ngFor='let post of posts$'>
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
</li>
```

but I cannot do similar in component:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.posts$.length; i++)
```

result with `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

And as far as I understand that error what I don't understand is why I can iterate through it in html and how it should be coded properly it in my component. Could you help?

Comment: Can you try logging `this.posts$` to see what it is exactly?

Comment: The point of TypeScript is to use typed variables. You chose `Object`, instead of using something like `Array<Post>`, where Post would be an interface describing the structure of the objects in the JSON array that the backend sends. Write and use appropriate types, and everything will compile, the IDE will auto-suggest completions, and your code will be much safer and more readable. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/, https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @mika I've tried to add console.log(this.posts$) at the end of ngOnInit() but I've got undefined.

Comment: @JBNizet I followed the tutorial tbh. Thank you, I'll have a look at that way.

Comment: The error message is correct: (plain) objects don't have a `length` property. If you're expecting that the service returns an array then make its type an array and not an object.

Comment: You need to add that line **inside** the subscribe callback. AJAX is **asynchronous**. The callback initializing the posts is executed long after ngOnInit finishes. That's why you need to use a callback in the first place.

Comment: Right. So console.log gives me array of objects: (100) [{…}, {…}, ..., {…}]. But when I try to use posts$: Array<Object> or Object[] or in fact any other type every this.posts$ further in code gives me an error: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Object[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'Object'

Comment: Because, as explained in the second link I posted on the HttpClient, your code should be `return this.http.get<Array<Post>>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');`. Also, you should really rename `posts$`to `posts`. The `$` suffix is used conventionally for Observables, but your variable is not an Observable, it's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `this.data.getPosts().subscribe()` and assigning data to `this.posts$`, you are assigning the actual data(array of posts) to the this.post$ variable, thats why you are able to see the result rendered. To unsubscribe properly what you can do is with the async pipe.

for example:

`<li *ngFor='let post of (posts$|async)'>
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
</li>`

and assign observable directly

`ngOnInit() {
    this.post$=this.data.getPosts();
}`